# IF conditions, data from cookie not validating

Tags: php

I need help, I have been at this for too many hours for me to no be embarrassed. Please, why am I not getting this?

```
function members_only() {
  $cookie_name = 'cookie_name';
  $error_url = home_url($path = '/403-error/');
  global $pagenow;
    $array_cookie_value = json_decode( stripslashes($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]), true);
    $woo_user_id = $array_cookie_value['user_id'];
    $user_meta = get_user_meta($woo_user_id);
    $user_order_status = $user_meta['doris_shop_enabled'][0];
  if ( is_admin() || is_front_page() || $pagenow == 'wp-login.php' || is_page('403-error') ) { 
    echo('Do nothing');
  } elseif ( !isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) || (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) && $user_order_status === 0) ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( $error_url );
    exit; 
  } else {
    echo("Very limited.");
  }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'members_only' );
```

Comment: what about explaining the problem, what you actually want to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: If user_order_status is 0 then I want the elseif to kick in.

Comment: You shouldn't get the user ID from a cookie, since the user can change that. Use a session variable instead.

Comment: Shouldn't you check if the cookie is set before you try to set `$array_cookie_value`?

Comment: Don't call `stripslashes`. Slashes in JSON are significant, and shouldn't be removed before decoding.

Comment: Have you checked `var_dump($array_cookie_value);` to see if it contains what you expect?

Comment: Thanks guys. It gives me what I want in var_dump. 
Regarding sessions, I don't know if that would work for me.

Comment: Still having problems.
WHat I want to do is to make the "$user_shop_enabled === 0" to work, I have tried to convert $user_shop_enabled to a int, bool and also "$user_shop_enabled == 0" and "$user_shop_enabled == "0". But nothing work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in Chrome data that was saved, outside of the cookie and hard-refresh which I make regularly. I needed to go into the Settings > Cookies and other website data and empty it all from there. After that I got it to work.
Yes I made some minor changes to the code also, but that was the main problem.

Thanks all for trying to help :)

Comment: You should validate your answer so we know the question has been answered